# Zeebe deployment via Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, camunda, zeebe

I want to deploy multiple BPMN files via Spring Boot Zeebe starter

This is how I am currently specifying my deployment

```java
@ZeebeDeployment(classPathResource = "customerFlow.bpmn")
```

Any suggestion on how to deploy more than two bpmn files?

Reference : https://github.com/zeebe-io/spring-zeebe

---

**Edit:**

I did try something like this

```java
@Autowired private ZeebeClient zeebeClient;

@PostConstruct
public void deploy(){
    final DeploymentEvent deployment = zeebeClient.newDeployCommand()
            .addResourceFromClasspath("customerFlow.bpmn")
            .send()
            .join();
}
```

Received following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: delegate is not running!
    at io.zeebe.spring.util.ZeebeAutoStartUpLifecycle.get(ZeebeAutoStartUpLifecycle.java:38)
    at io.zeebe.spring.client.ZeebeClientLifecycle.newDeployCommand(ZeebeClientLifecycle.java:71)
    at com.lendingkart.flows.app.App.deploy(App.java:51)
```

Comment: I think this was added with https://github.com/zeebe-io/spring-zeebe/pull/74

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working for my case

```
@Component
public class ZeebeDeployer {

    @Value("${zeebe.client.broker.contactPoint}")
    private String zeebeBroker;

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ZeebeDeployer.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void deploy(){
        try(ZeebeClient client = ZeebeClient.newClientBuilder()
                    // change the contact point if needed
                    .brokerContactPoint(zeebeBroker)
                    .usePlaintext()
                    .build();){

            client.newDeployCommand()
                .addResourceFromClasspath("abc.bpmn")
                .addResourceFromClasspath("xyz.bpmn")
                .send()
                .join();
        }catch (Exception e){
            //Todo: better to throw custom exception here
            logger.error("Zeebe deployment failed {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can hand over a list of resources in the DeploymentAnnoation:

```
@ZeebeDeployment(classPathResources = {"customerFlow.bpmn", "secondFile.bpmn"})
```

I just updated the readme to reflect this:

https://github.com/zeebe-io/spring-zeebe/blob/master/README.md#deploy-workflow-models

Comment: Hi thanks for considering,
but is it released? I don't see this option in latest version 0.23.2.

Can you suggest a way to deploy it during @PostConstruct.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards are also supported now like so:

```
@Deployment(resources = {"classpath*:/bpmn/**/*.bpmn", "classpath*:/dmn/**/*.dmn"})
```

This will deploy all files nested in a bpmn folder that end with .bpmn and all files nested in a dmn foldeer that end with .dmn

Reference: https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/spring-zeebe?tab=readme-ov-file#deploy-process-models